# Word / Phrase Assistance of Mother Nature

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There is a word, "Qualia", in which details the subjective and qualitative experiences and sensations a person has. An example of this is immeasurable data such as the way listening to a stream or river makes you feel inside.

I'd love to find a phrase or word I can use in combination with this that sort of summarizes the Qualia "of nature" or "mother earth" without it being so long. I originally settled on "terra" but in the scheme of things it seemed to general.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. "Qualia Natura" might be a possibility.

Comment: Interesting, forgive my silliness but is that latin for Nature? I suppose mushed together it could mean the immeasurable feelings that nature provides

Comment: @Illu...Qualia Natura was not an answer to your question, but just something to think on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "terra", how about "Gaia" (or "Gaea")? Using the name of a Greek-mythological deity gives more of that primal, emotional tug you're going for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia